# Playing a midifile through a workstation

Tags: midi, playback

Can you play a midifile thorough a workstation (via connected laptop) but play a sound on the keyboard not in the midifile? And if so, how? Thank You.

Comment: do you have an example of what you are trying to do? What software are you using?

Comment: It's not quite clear what's being asked here, but I think it's close - could you edit your answer to clarify?  Maybe give an example?  I *think* you're asking if it's possible to play back the contents of a MIDI file, but at the same time ALSO be sending in new MIDI information from a keyboard as it's playing.  But I don't want to answer the wrong question!

Comment: @Bob, I think that is what he is asking. Though I don't understand where the laptop comes in.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is definitely possible.  What you want to do is hook up that keyboard/synth via MIDI to your computer, and set the MIDI out to the MIDI that goes to the keyboard.

In XP, you can find this under Control Panel, Sounds and Audio Devices, the Audio tab, and down towards the bottom, MIDI music playback.  Change the default device.  Once you've done this, play a MIDI file with just about anything, and your keyboard will handle it.

Sequencer software will often use its own independent MIDI configuration, so if you are using something more than a typical media player, check its settings for the primary MIDI out to use.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the workstation you are using.

Most should be able to play MIDI files.

You should not need to use a laptop if you can load the MIDI file into the workstation.

Comment: At this point it's not clear what the question is. "Workstation" may not be a general purpose personal computer workstation.